# Dynamically alter settings in program

Tags: ubuntu, python, automation

Can Python or some Robotic Process Automation tool be used to control settings and behaviour of a program?

For example, while using VLC player, can I run a script which changes the settings like:

> If looping is on, then do not pause at the last frame. Else pause at the last frame.

I have searched the internet for a technique to do so, but found no suitable tool/library to dynamically alter settings of a program.

Although scripting VLC is my current use case, I am interested in generally automating programs. Using a general technique/tool/library to automate program settings in Ubuntu is probably a better approach than writing an add-on or extension for a particular program, just to accomplish one task.

Comment: Are you asking if programs can be automated using other programs, or if VLC can be scripted? Please limit your post to a single, specific question.

Comment: Scripting VLC is my current use case. But I am interested in generally automating programs. I found no tool in Ubuntu which can do this. I am not sure how to modify the question. I am not interested in learning how to write an add-on or extension for a particular program, just to accomplish one task.

Comment: Use the EDIT button to modify the question. It's right there under the question itself. Limit your question to that one task you are trying to accomplish.